# JSF - <f:selectItems> not getting value from a Bean

Tags: maven, jsf, web-applications, xhtml

I was building a very simple WebApp with Maven, to create a small REST Api (while using JSF).

In one of my beans (amongst other methods and variables) I created a very simple `List` just to test if I could get its options in JSF `<p:selectItems>`

Here's the bean code:

```
 @ManagedBean(name="er", eager=true)
 public class ExchangeRates {
        private List<String> frase = new ArrayList<>();

            public List<String> getFrase() {
                frase.add("opcao1");
                frase.add("opcao2");
                return frase;
            }

            public void setFrase(List<String> frase) {
                this.frase = frase;
            }
/*some more code that doesn't use "frase"*/
```

And here's the (xhtml) JSF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Currency Conversion REST Api</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1>Currency Conversion</h1>

        <h:form>               
            <h:outputLabel for="txtName">
                           <h:outputText value="Quantity:  " />
            </h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="txtNamea" value="#{er.quantity}" />

            <br></br><br></br>

            <h:outputLabel for="currency1" value="Convert from:  "/> 
                <h:selectOneMenu id="currency1" value="#{er.currency1}" style="width:70px">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{er.frase}" />
                </h:selectOneMenu>

        </h:form> 
    </h:body>
</html>
```

The dropdown created by `<f:selectItems>` was supposed to give me the 2 options ("opcao1" and "opcao2"). However, when I click it it acts as if I didn't assign any variable or values to it, what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I doubt in the way you imported the "core" JSF name space. Try this : `xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core`.

Comment: @omar: why? if it is wrong it would not render at all.

Comment: Possibly you have to assign `var` `itemLabel` and `itemValue`. `<f:selectItems value="#{er.frase}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item}" itemValue="#{item}"/>`

Comment: @Reactor: Any progress? It is good practice in Stackoverflow that if you ask a question, you in the week after it, monitor the responses/comments closely and reply...